# converting vim syntax highlighting into vscode syntax highlighting

Tags: visual-studio-code, vim, syntax-highlighting

I've looked around - and could not find a way to automatically do this. so:

I have some syntax highlighting I built in vim I want to transfer over to vscode. and I'm getting stuck on at least 2 parts.

so far here's where I'm at: I've build a vscode language extension - set up some basic syntax rules, and have that copied over to the vscode config folder.

the parts I'm having trouble with - I could use some clarity in what some fields mean - naming conventions.

and nested parsing of syntax, things only appearing in other elements.

below is the bit I added on top of the vim-markdown syntax.

```
syntax region spokenWord start=/\v"/ skip=/\v\\./ end=/\v"/ contained
syntax region thoughtWord start=/\v'/ skip=/\v\\./ end=/\v'/ contained
syntax region codeWord start=/\v`/ skip=/\v\\./ end=/\v`/ contained contains=objkw,spokenWord,thoughtWord,action,description,executekw
syntax region action start=/\v*/ skip=/\v\\./ end=/\v*/ contained
syntax region description start=/\~/ skip=/\v\\./ end=/\~/ contained

syntax match executekw "[e][x][e]\s" contained
syntax match objkw "[.][\w]+" contained
syntax region BLOCK start=/{/ skip=/\s+/ end=/}/ contains=spokenWord,thoughtWord,codeWord,action,description

highlight link spokenWord String
hi thoughtWord ctermfg=red
hi codeWord ctermfg=gray
highlight link action function
highlight link description Statement
hi BLOCK guibg=#FF00FF ctermfg=magenta cterm=bold guifg=#00FF00
hi exepm ctermfg=green
hi objP ctermfg=red
hi fntk ctermfg=blue
hi fnnm ctermfg=130
hi executekw ctermfg=130
hi objkw ctermfg=130
```

which results in this look:
[image: vim color scheme]

what I have so far for the vs code syntax is as follows:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/martinring/tmlanguage/master/tmlanguage.json",
    "name": "MDX",
    "patterns": [
        {
            "include": "#keywords"
        },
        {
            "include": "#strings"
        },
        {
            "include":"#thought"
        },
        {
            "include":"#action"
        },
        {
            "include":"#description"
        },
        {
            "include":"#code"
        },
        {
            "include":"#block"

        },
        {
            "include":"#object"
        }
    ],
    "repository": {
        "keywords": {
            "patterns": [{
                "name": "keyword.control.markdownextened",
                "match": "\\b(EXE|IF|WHILE|FOR|RETURN)\\b"
            }]
        },
        "strings": {
            "name": "string.quoted.double.markdownextened",
            "begin": "\"",
            "end": "\"",
            "patterns": [
                {
                    "name": "constant.character.escape.markdownextened",
                    "match": "\\\\."
                }
            ]
        },
        "thought":{
            "name": "thought.quoted.single.markdownextened",
            "begin": "'",
            "end": "'",
            "patterns": [
                {
                    "name": "constant.character.escape.markdownextened",
                    "match": "\\\\."
                }
            ]
        },
        "action":{
            "name": "action.asterisk.markdownextened",
            "begin": "*",
            "end": "*",
            "patterns": [
                {
                    "name": "constant.character.escape.markdownextened",
                    "match": "\\\\."
                }
            ]
        },
        "description":{
            "name": "action.tilde.markdownextened",
            "begin": "~",
            "end": "~",
            "patterns": [
                {
                    "name": "constant.character.escape.markdownextened",
                    "match": "\\\\."
                }
            ]
        
        },
        "code":{
            "name": "action.grave.markdownextened",
            "begin": "`",
            "end": "`",
            "patterns": [
                {
                    "name": "constant.character.escape.markdownextened",
                    "match": "\\\\."
                }
            ]
        
        },
        "block":{
            "name": "action.braces.markdownextened",
            "begin": "{",
            "end": "}",
            "patterns": [
                {
                    "name": "constant.character.escape.markdownextened",
                    "match": "\\\\."
                }
            ]
        },
        "object":{
            "name": "action.object.markdownextened",
            "patterns": [
                {
                    "name": "action.object.markdownextened",
                    "match": "/[.][\\w]/"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "scopeName": "source.markdown"
}
```

I could not find a guide anywhere on converting vim syntax highlighting into vscode syntax highlighting. I'll be reading though the documentation until I figure this out - but would love some help!

Comment: if the TextMate Grammar is working, the Theme should color the parts according to the scopes

Answer (score 1):

Are you wanting to do a one off conversion
or a tool to continuously convert a large amount of highlighters?

I doubt there will be many, if at all any, large public vim to vscode converters tools

I am going to assume your vscode example above is working
and you have read up on pages like

[Your First Extension Visual Studio Code Extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/get-started/your-first-extension)

[Syntax Highlight Guide Visual Studio Code Extension](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide)

[Writing a TextMate Grammar Some Lessons Learned](https://www.apeth.com/nonblog/stories/textmatebundle.html)
[oniguruma/RE at master kkos/oniguruma](https://github.com/kkos/oniguruma/blob/master/doc/RE)

I would highly suggest looking at other people's highlighters [Where are extensions installed?](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace#_where-are-extensions-installed)
and download a TextMate syntax highlighter
[TextMate Languages](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Togusa09.tmlanguage) or (my own) [Text Mate Language Syntax Highlighter](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redcmd.tmlanguage-syntax-highlighter)

Colours are defined by your current theme
Your theme defines colours based on the scopename that you give to each token in your highlighter

Comment: haven't found all of those links. and https://www.apeth.com/nonblog/stories/textmatebundle.html was a helpful read.

Comment: BTW you must escape a `*` to be able to use it. `\\*`
and "`/[.][\\w]/`" can be reduced to "`\\.\\w`"